# Interval, stops when in othertab. when return plays all the interval after each other

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Bit of a weird title but here what i got.

I have found this question asked a couple of times but the awnsers dont seem to work properly for me

what i got is a footer that bounces up and down to catch your attention, when you hover over it it will expand showing a filter.

Now it works perfectly in the window but when i move to a other tab and go back to the site, it will play all the bounces after each other.

I have read an article that chrome slows down intervals when in another tab to improve cpu speed.

I now have the timer only played when the window is set to focus, and disabled when it is set to blur.
But this doesnt work 100% of the time.

```
var $bounceInter = 6000;

function mycode() {
    if($bounceOn == true) {
            $("#footer").animate({bottom:"+=20px"},150, 'swing').animate({bottom:"-=20px"},150, 'swing').animate({bottom:"+=10px"},100, 'swing').animate({bottom:"-=10px"},100,"swing",function(){$("#footer").data("bouncing", false);});
    }
    clearTimeout($bounceTimer);
  $bounceTimer = setTimeout(mycode, $bounceInter); // repeat myself
}


$(window).focus(function() {
    $bounceTimer = setTimeout(mycode, $bounceInter);
});

$(window).blur(function() {
    clearTimeout($bounceTimer);
});

var $bounceTimer = setTimeout(mycode, $bounceInter);
```

Any other possible fixes?

I have got the bounce code from another person, maybe the problem is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorporate the [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) method in your code. Since your code is not complete (what's the role of `$bounceOn`? Probably set on hover or something), I will highlight the generic steps, based on your function names. I'm removing the `$` prefix, because it's used to mark jQuery objects, by convention.

For convenience, we're using a normalizing the API which uses the native (prefixed) `requestAnimationFrame` method and a polyfill when necessary. The polyfill is created by Erik Moller, and can be found [on his blog](http://my.opera.com/emoller/blog/2011/12/20/requestanimationframe-for-smart-er-animating).

```
// Minimum delay between each call
var bounceInter = 6000
  , raf
  , bounceTimer;

function nextAnimationStep() {
    raf = requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        // Code here (eg animation)
        bounceTimer = setTimeout(nextAnimationStep, bounceInter);
    });
}

// Initial step
nextAnimationStep();

// To cancel animation (to restart, just call `nextAnimationStep();` ):
cancelAnimationFrame(raf);
clearTimeout(bounceTimer);
```

Here's your animation, with the gaps filled in: http://jsfiddle.net/exPeP/1.

Comment: thanks it works! 
the bounceOn is set to false whenever the footer is expanded so that it cannot bounce.